# Who started xterm in my debian xterm+lightdm kiosk system?

Tags: debian, x11, session, lightdm

I have stripped my full desktop debian 7 x64 to the bare, leaving just  xorg and lightdm for a kiosk application.

I have changed the lighdm configuration to auto-login a user. When I boot, this works fine, xorg starts up and without prompt the user is logged in.

However upon login an xterm window starts in the upper left-hand corner of the screen. I have tried in vain to figure out which instance actually started that xterm!

I would of course want to replace it with my kiosk binary wrapped in a watchdog script.

Comment: Have you looked in `/etc/X11`?

Comment: Boy have I looked there... I even did a grep -iR xterm / at one point without getting any wiser.

Comment: try `pstree`....

Comment: good idea! I allready did ps auxf and it is clear that xterm is started by lightdm, however I am more interrested in knowing which configuration option in which configuration file is responsible. I guess that must be the lightdm.conf file, however it is not at all clear to my how it selected to start xterm

Comment: I made a discovery! lightdm uses /etc/X11/Xsession which on debian is a huge mess of scripts calling eachoter. This in turn is responsible for calling ~/.xsession The reason why xterm was started is because I did not have ~/.xsession. And this is the fun part: the ~/.xinitrc file is no longer used for never versions of xorg, so even if you have it, it will still revert to the xterm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Debian xterm is automatically started if no window manager is selected.

Even if you have no slightest idea about who started xterm easiest way to find this out: as root rename `/usr/bin/xterm` to `/usr/bin/xterm_`. Create /usr/bin/xterm script:

```
#!/bin/bash
( echo $$; ps -f --forest ) >/tmp/xterm.txt
```

Than take a look into output.

Comment: That's not just a Debian thing. It's what `startx` or `xinit` traditionally does if you have not `~/.xinitrc`.

Comment: Actually there is no .xinitrc anymore. It's called .xsession now for some reason.